# Not enough Results in Custom Search Engine (Google search API)

Tags: search, google-search-api, google-custom-search

I have a really big problem:

- I'm using the Google Custom Search Engine `CSE` with the REST API to find some URL but a lot of search engine results are missing.
- I look on the internet about this fact and a lot of people have the same problem. e.g

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173457/why-google-web-search-api-custom-search-engine-and-page-search-results-are-diff
- If I used the keyword "site:" to see how many page are indexed in `CSE` I found a few result but in a normal web browser I found about 93% more results.
- Here is the test for "site:stackoverflow.com"

  ```
  Web : 43 400 000 results
  CSE : 3 190 000
  ```

Anyone has experienced the same ?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.itsupportguides.com/tech-tips-tricks/google-custom-search-not-showing-all-results/)? Either way, [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) may be a better place to get this answered.

Comment: Thank you for the advice ! I'll try it right now.